# ダークモードが利用可能になりました！

Tags: 討議, ダークモード

翻訳をしてくれた[@aki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki)に感謝します。

---

サイトのダークモード実装はなにか難しいのでしょうか？[サードパーティの拡張機能](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336626/274323)でもできるのでは？そうかもしれません..。しかしこれまで実装にしようとする度に、[あらゆる技術的な複雑さが増してゆきました](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/issues/297)。「[Stacks styles](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/)」やサイトの大部分のマイグレーションによって状況が変わり、その結果、2019年7月にやっとダークモードの可能性を検討し始めることとなりました。[2020年の初めに、Aaronがダークモードの対応を模索し](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/356)3月末までに[ベータダークモードが英語版のStack Overflowで利用可能になりました](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/564240)。

今日は大変嬉しいことにスタック・オーバーフロー日本語版のユーザーのみなさんへダークモードが利用できるようになったことをお知らせいたします！

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ダークモードは現在、メインサイト（多言語版を含む全てのStack Overflowサイト）のみ利用可能です。MSEやSEネットワークのサイトを含むメタサイトでダークモードを実装することは、依然として難しいです。

[ダークモードの詳細はAaronのブログ投稿（英語）をご覧ください。](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/31/building-dark-mode-on-stack-overflow/)

#### ダークモードをオンにする方法：

有効にするには、スタック・オーバーフローのプロフィールにアクセスし、[プロフィールと設定を編集]タブに移動し、[サイト設定]の下の[基本設定]までスクロールし、ページ上部の[テーマ]セクションを見つけます。3つのオプションがあり、ライト、ダーク、それから「システム設定」であなたのシステムの好みに基づいてテーマを調整することもできます。

[image: Screenshot of the preferences page, showing the three options, light, dark, and system setting.]
(パスのGIFを見るには画像をクリック)

#### バグを報告する方法は？

バグを見つけた場合は、スタック・オーバーフローのメタ、又はStack Overflow英語版（本家）のメタサイトに質問を投稿してください。

みなさんのフィードバックを楽しみにしております！